# Moving Point in a set of non-concurrent lines

Tags: euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

In a plane we have N lines, no two of which are parallel or perpendicular, and no three of which are concurrent. A cartesian system of coordinates is chosen for the plane with one of the lines as the X-axis. A point P is located at the origin of the coordinate system and starts moving along the positive X-axis with constant velocity. Whenever P reaches the intersection of two lines, it continues along the line it just reached in the direction that increases its X-coordinate. Show that it is possible to choose the system of coordinates in such a way that P visits points from all N lines

Comment: If you don't explain what you have tried so far, some guys here will burn you at stake :)

Comment: I just have enumarated some properties but dont havr any strategy how to attack this. I m ansious about the solution